# Want to make new version of formatted string from old version in python

Tags: python, string

This a old version formatted string. I want to convert this code for new version of formatted string and how this vertical printing is working.

```
cat1 = 2
cat2 = 3
cat3 = 1
cat4 = 4

header = ['0-29', '30-39', '40-69', '70-100']
print(' '.join(header))
for x in range(max(cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4)):
    print(" {0}     {1}     {2}     {3}".format(
        '*' if x < cat1 else ' ',
        '*' if x < cat2 else ' ',
        '*' if x < cat3 else ' ',
        '*' if x < cat4 else ' '
    ))
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Does this code work, and you are looking for a better solution? Does it *not* work, in which case what should it do that it isn't currently doing?

Comment: This is work, But this is a old version of formatted strings. I want to do this in new version, as print(f ' write something {variable} ')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just replace the placeholders with the actual expressions:

```
print(f" {'*' if x < cat1 else ' '}     {'*' if x < cat2 else ' '}     {'*' if x < cat3 else ' '}     {'*' if x < cat4 else ' '}")
```

Comment: What is the meaning of x<cat1

Comment: The same thing as before. The fields in an f-string are arbitrary Python expressions.

Comment: Can you please give me an explanation

Comment: I don't know what additional explanation I can give: `"{0} {1}".format(x, y)` is the same as `f"{x} {y}"`; you are basically just inlining the arguments to `format`.

Comment: About the whole code of my first one. Its not my question. But can you please help, Its an additional help for me.

Comment: No, I am not expanding my answer to cover a full explanation of something never mentioned in the original question.